# Recover a ESXi system

Tags: esxi

I messed up a cronjob on my ESXi system that is now putting it into a boot loop. I am familiar with recovering a Linux system through mounting and editing the files, but I can't figure out how to do that for ESXi. I created the cronjob through a script in /etc/rc.local.. which of the multiple partitions do I have to mount to get that?

Comment: We know nothing about your ESXi configuration.  Can you narrow down the scope of your question?

Comment: Its a simple lab setup, ESXi running on a dell server, hosting two virtual machines. I created a cronjob (editing /etc/rc.local, following this guide http://www.jules.fm/Logbook/files/add_cron_job_vmware.html) in ESXi to clear out a configuration file and reboot the system, which was supposed to be once a month but it is running every time at boot. I figured the easiest way is to liveboot in, mount the system and remove my rc.local changes.

Comment: The file in question is a configuration file.  This article, [Editing configuration files in VMware ESXi and ESX (1017022)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1017022) should answer your question.

Comment: My system reboots as soon as it boots up though.. is there a way to enter a 'recovery' mode that would prevent the rc.local scripts from running?

Comment: [Modifying the rc.local or local.sh file in ESX/ESXi to execute commands while booting (2043564)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2043564)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESXi stores its malleable etc files (at least on my system) on the 5th partition (sda5), in a file archive file state.tgz. Unpacking that, then editing the appropriate file, repacking and replacing got me working again.